# Find specific character in a string, remove it, turn the rest of the characters to number and divide by 5

Tags: r, string, character

I'm working with a data frame in R. It has about 18 columns with numbers in them. Some cells have a "P" followed by a number. For these cases I'd like to remove the "P", turn the rest of the characters to a number and then take that number and divide by 5.

```
    > Replace<-data.frame(group=c("P4", "25", "4", "P1", "25"))
    > Replace
    group
    1    P4
    2    25
    3     4
    4    P1
    5    25
    >
```

For example, within "Replace" I'd like "P4" to be "0.8" and "P1" to be "0.2". But "25", "4", and "25" should stay the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "P", replacement = "", Replace$group))/5))`. Then apply that to all your columns.

Comment: Where should the parentheses go so that it doesn't divide each one by 5?

Comment: you would need to use ifelse. @Psidom's answer is best and uses the `dplyr` package - i suggest using that.

Comment: `sapply(gsub('P', '1 / 5 * ', Replace$group), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
Replace <- mutate(Replace, group = ifelse(grepl("P", group),
                  as.numeric(gsub("P", "", group))/5, as.character(group)))
```

Comment: This is perfect, works beautifully. I think I can just then do all columns at once by collapsing them using tidyr. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use `mutate_each()` function. `mutate_each(Replace, funs(ifelse(grepl("P", .), as.numeric(gsub("P", "",  .))/5, as.character(.))))`